# Table Column type for storing json data from laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I would like to store some json data on one of the table's column.
Eg.

```
{option: 1, status: false}
```

What is the column type be set as, long text? And is the storing json part using attribute casting ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the text or longtext type depending of your application requirements.

```
The maximum length of text input is: 65,535 (216−1) bytes = 64 KiB
The maximum length of longtext input is: 4,294,967,295 (232−1) bytes =  4 GiB
```

The usage of attribute casting is here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting